# Why is vi apparently broken (viminfo error E576), and how can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, vi

I am proficient at using Unix/Linux, but I am not an expert.  If I want to open a file (for example, `file.txt`), I use `vi`:

```
vi file.txt
```

This opens the file, and if I want to close it, I use `:q!`.  I have been using this method for the two years that I have been using Unix/Linux.  My institution has a cluster running Ubuntu Linux.

Today, however, I tried to open a file, and I got these error messages:

```
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: newest to oldest):
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CJ
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CG
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CC
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/OEP
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CEP
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/dih
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/ang
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ??b
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/xvg
E136: viminfo: Too many errors, skipping rest of file
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  I get the same messages:

```
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: newest to oldest):
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CJ
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CG
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CC
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/OEP
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/CEP
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/dih
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/ang
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ??b
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: ?/xvg
E136: viminfo: Too many errors, skipping rest of file
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Again I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and finally the file opens for reading/editing.  However, the problem repeats when I try to close the file using `:q!`, and also when I try to open any other file using `vi`.

The key words `CJ`, `CG`, `CC`, `OEP`, `CEP`, `dih`, `ang`, and `xvg` (I am not sure about `b`, though) are all strings that often appear in files that I read using `vi`, although I am not certain that they all exist in the particular file that I am opening (I do not think so).  Thus, perhaps something is wrong with my `viminfo` file?  However, I *am* using `vi`, *not* `vim`.

I am not sure what has happened; do you have any suggestions of how I can diagnose, and possibly fix, this problem?

Comment: Is your `~/.viminfo` corrupt?  Try moving it elsewhere and see if the problem returns.  Keep in mind many systems that provide `vim` simply provide `vi` as a symlink to `vim`.

Comment: *I am using vi, not vim.* Are you sure? `vi` is often aliased to `vim` (check with `which vi` and then `file` on that location).

Comment: On most linux systems, vi is a symlink to vim, so you might have a corrupt viminfo.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Thanks!  When I enter `which vi`, I get the output `/usr/bin/vi`.  When I enter `file /usr/bin/vi`, I obtain the output `/usr/bin/vi: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/vi'`.  Does this mean I am using `vi`?

Comment: @Andrew - Ok, so do `file /etc/alternatives/vi`. I expect that will tell you you are actually running `vim`.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Thanks! Indeed, when I enter `file /etc/alternatives/vi`, I obtain `/etc/alternatives/vi: symbolic link to '/usr/bin/vim.basic'`. So, you are right -- I am actually running `vim`. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do this:

```
rm -f ~/.viminfo
```

The `.viminfo` file keeps metadata about various useful, but non-critical state information. Yours is corrupt. Remove it.

Comment: It would be more risk averse to move  `.viminfo`  rather than remove it. For example if you are working on a large code-base it may be very painful to reconstruct your marks.

Comment: @bahamat @donothingsuccessfully Thanks to all for your time!  Moving `.viminfo` (risk averse method) fixes the problem.  So I guess my `.viminfo` file was corrupted.  Sincere thanks for your help.  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2):

The vim error E576 happens when you've some syntax error in your `.viminfo` file which stores your command and file history, etc.

The corruption may happen when you're out-of-space or your storage engine is faulty.
You may try to edit `~/.viminfo`, locate  and remove the invalid lines, eventually to rename it to different name and just to remove it.

You also can use `-i {viminfo}` parameter to specify the different .viminfo file.