# I've broken vi (E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line:) - how do I fix it?

Tags: vim, root

I am very much new to Debian, and have been using vi/vim to harden my SSH settings under sshd_config.

Recently I've had a persistent error message:

```
E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line:
```

I've followed the replies at the similar thread [Why is vi apparently broken (viminfo error E576), and how can I fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59155/why-is-vi-apparently-broken-viminfo-error-e576-and-how-can-i-fix-it?newreg=9fc75d75bd984f5291ca7e79d81c497d) including `rm -f ~/.viminfo`, to no avail. I've tried deleting everything below `# History of marks within files (newest to oldest):`, which hasn't worked either.

I tried removing and reinstalling `vim` as well, but the issue still persists. I'm unsure how to move `.viminfo` as one of the replies suggested - I'm loathe to risk breaking things further until I understand what's gone wrong first.

Strangely, when I open `.viminfo` it doesn't throw up the error, but when I open `sshd_config` or `ssh_config` it does. Could I have corrupted these files somehow?

As far as I'm aware `vi`/`vim` are the same in Debian.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about reinstalling `vim` - how did you do that? Please include exact commands.

Comment: Are you using `vi`/`vim` as another user (perhaps via `sudo`)? Just want to make sure you're targeting the appropriate .viminfo file...

Comment: [Oh](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/elvis-tiny/vi.1.en.html) [no](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/nvi/vi.1.en.html) [they](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/vis/vi.1.en.html) [are](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/vile/vi.1.en.html) [not](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/levee/vi.1.en.html).

Comment: @Panki I ran `sudo apt-get purge vim && sudo apt-get install vim` which I understand uninstalled then reinstalled `vim`.

@JeffSchaller - I tried `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` which didn't throw up the E576 error, so you're right looks like it's only giving the error for the user `sudo`?

Comment: Consider addressing Jeff's comment too. If you ran the editor as another user, then deleting or "fixing" your own `.viminfo` file would be of no use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic file is `.viminfo` in the user's home directory. Reinstalling vim wouldn't help since the problematic file is a per-account file, not a system file.

This file contains history information: things like the last files you opened, the last search queries, etc. If you remove it, you'll just start with a fresh history. Your customizations are in a different file (`.vimrc`).

`rm -f ~/.viminfo` solves the problem on your account. But from the symptoms you describe (no problem when editing `.viminfo`, but problem editing `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`), I deduce that the problem is not on your account, it's on the root account. You haven't broken `vim`, you've broken `sudo vim`. (This is important information, by the way: you should have stated this in the question and not left us to guess.) So you need to remove (or fix) the `.viminfo` file in the administrator (`root`) account:

```
sudo rm /root/.viminfo
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you for your answer, I understand now.